# Upload CodeIgniter project to cpanel

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I have worked on that the whole day, but I couldn't find why I always get the CI 404 Page not found. The project works very well in localhost. What could be the problem?
This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|js|jq|uploads|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I suspect the default controller can't be found.

What more do you think I should show you?

I will be grateful for your answers.

PD: I use CI 2.1.2

Comment: And it works if you disable htaccess and open index.php?

Comment: yes, it works too, but the error is the same

Comment: if you still get the error, it means it's not working... do you have any capital letters in your controller name? What is your base_url? You need to show more info if you want someone to help you.

Comment: mm yes, for example, I have "class Blog" in "Blog.php"
What can I do? (I use CI 2.1.2)

Comment: Naming conventions say use lowercase for filenames and capitalized class names, but I doubt that's breaking your app... I meant maybe you had unwanted capitals in your URL, as some servers are case-sensitive. Also try changing your uri_protocol in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set up everything right, then try changing your last line to: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/?$1 [L]`

EDIT

Since it's not working when you disable .htaccess and use index.php, you need to check your config.php for things like base_url, index_page, uri_protocol, etc... and routes.php and make sure the default controller is not capitalized (read more about the naming conventions, but I wrote you the general idea in the comments).

Comment: Hey buddy thanks a lot! it seems that the error was caused by the capital leters. I feel a little stupid... I will see how it works

Comment: You're welcome! :) No need to feel stupid as I'm sure you're learned something new and you'll never make the same mistake again. Also, don't forget to select the answer if it really helped you.